# How can I subctract two values in different rows, grouping them for another variable?

Tags: r

I have the following dataset

```
 Month   Year   Hotel_Name   Reviewer_Score  
 8       2015   ambassador         7.711111
 9       2015   ambassador         8.400000
 12      2015   ambassador         9.457890
 2       2016   ambassador         8.398733
 4       2015   nh hotel           8.934023
 7       2015   nh hotel           7.345532
 11      2015   nh hotel           6.893445
 1       2016   nh hotel           8.834923
```

I would like to know the difference between the first score and last score for each hotel and group them in a new table by `Hotel_Name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure if you wanted the difference between first and last score (by date, latest - earliest) or first and last score (by value, max - min)

For the first

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
ans1 <- df %>%
         group_by(Hotel_Name) %>%
         arrange(Hotel_Name, parse_date_time(paste(Month, Year), "my")) %>%
         summarise(Diff = abs(last(Reviewer_Score) - first(Reviewer_Score)))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  # Hotel_Name     Diff
      # <fctr>    <dbl>
# 1 ambassador 0.687622
# 2   nh_hotel 0.099100
```

And for the second

```
ans2 <- df %>%
         group_by(Hotel_Name) %>%
         summarise(Diff = max(Reviewer_Score) - min(Reviewer_Score))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  # Hotel_Name     Diff
      # <fctr>    <dbl>
# 1 ambassador 1.746779
# 2   nh_hotel 2.040578
```

Your data

```
df <- read.table(text="Month   Year   Hotel_Name   Reviewer_Score  
 8       2015   ambassador         7.711111
 9       2015   ambassador         8.400000
 12      2015   ambassador         9.457890
 2       2016   ambassador         8.398733
 4       2015   nh_hotel           8.934023
 7       2015   nh_hotel           7.345532
 11      2015   nh_hotel           6.893445
 1       2016   nh_hotel           8.834923", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: thank you @CPak and sorry!!I'm asking the difference between the first and last score by date!!